# highcharts - error when updating a series to have less categories than previously

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm having an issue with updating a highcharts chart when the new data has fewer columns (categories) than it had previously.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ggoforth/bZAF7/

Consider I have a chart like:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['pizza', 'french fries']  
    },
    series: [{
        data: [55, 32]   
    }]
});
```

This will render a column chart with two columns.  Then, via some button I do:

```
chart.series[0].setData([55, 32, 17], false);
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['pizza', 'french fries', 'nachos'], false);
chart.redraw();
```

This will then update the chart to have three columns.  This all works just fine.  However, if at a later time, I then refresh the chart with 2 columns again:

```
chart.series[0].setData([55, 32], false);
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['pizza', 'french fries'], false);
chart.redraw();
```

I get the error "options is undefined".  This is reproducible, and there is a fiddle demonstrating the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/ggoforth/bZAF7/

Is there some kind of "reset" I need to do on the chart first before setting the new data?  Like I said, it works when going from 2 columns -> 3 columns, but not vice versa.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the following line:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['pizza', 'french fries'], false);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bZAF7/5/)**

So as you can see, the problem is that your new data can't have less than your categories number, so **you have to update your categories first than your serie**. Like the following example.
http://jsfiddle.net/bZAF7/6/

So, to solve this problem you have to reverse the following lines.

```
chart.series[0].setData([55, 32], false);
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['pizza', 'french fries'], false);
```

**Update**: As Greg said on the comments, it's a bug from Highcharts https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/970 probably it's fixed on the newest Highcharts release.

Comment: Interesting, so it's the categories that actually cause the problem.  What do you do if the categories change?  In my case the categories do change (although I didn't highlight that in the fiddle).

Comment: Ricardo, this is exactly my issue.  I was updating the data first, then the categories, simply moving that order around fixes my issue.  With this fix I don't have to remove the series, add an empty one, set the data, etc...pefect! solution accepted.

Comment: @Greg That's the idea, if you have to remove and add again you'll loss performance.

Comment: For what it's worth, I mentioned this bug to the developers and they opened a bug for it (https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/970) which was actually closed 8 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you remove the series and re-add it:

```
   try {
        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({});
        chart.series[0].setData([55, 32], false);
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['pizza', 'french fries'], false);
        chart.redraw();
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);   
    }
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/bZAF7/4/).

Comment: Awesome, this is a step in the right direction.  In my case color palette is important, so I need the new charts to observe the previous color settings, however this seems to move through the defaults.  Any idea how to retain the existing color palette?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Marks approach worked (kinda), however Ricardo's addressed the actual issue (setting data before categories), keeps the current color palette, and requires less code.  Thanks for the answers guys!

Comment: Hey now, why the down vote?  I will admIt @RicardoLohmann answer is the correct way to go, but I was trying to help...

Comment: @Mark upvoted you back to 1. I used the same hack to get it to work properly (had issues with the rendering expecting an extra column when I removed it)

Comment: @Greg 

chart.addSeries(chart.options.series[0],false);

Will add your series back with the original settings